# how to skip all the lint errors for a C file

Tags: c, lint, pc-lint

how to skip all the lint errors for a C file?
Is there any way to skip all the lint errors for specific file with any options?

I am able to skip individual error with below option:

```
/*lint -save -e40 */
*lint -restore */
```

Comment: Don't call lint on that file?

Comment: Most of the bad questions here come from people who turn off lint/warnings and then wonder why their code doesn't work. There are very few cases where a warning isn't pointing out something you should fix instead of hide.

Answer (score 0):

Long time passed since I last used Lint.
I hope I am not mistaking...

According to: http://www.gimpel.com/Discussion.cfm?ThreadID=3410

The syntax is:

```
/*lint -save -e* */
...
/*lint -restore */
```